# Excel Condition-Formatting: Cells flagged as false duplicate when starting with '<'

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I found that any cell which starts with a '<' will identify as a duplicate with any other cell that starts with a '<'. This happens even when the cells are unique. Are there any methods to stop this behavior? I have not been able to identify the mechanism causing this.

This happens only for '<', not '>'. It happens regardless whether the braces are closed or open.

I found I can stop this when there is whitespace as a first character but I'd like to find a solution that is a bit more transparent to the user. The spreadsheet with this issue is a tool used by many people, technical and non-technical.

I have a list of cells that has conditional formatting turned on to flag any duplicates. The data in the cells already has a convention to show information in <> braces. E.g `<Computer> Office`, or `<Printer> Mezzanine`. The majority of my list is getting flagged as duplicate and I am unable to see which items are actually duplicate.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: The find duplicates must use something similar to COUNTIF().  Use a formula instead: `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(B2=$B$2:$E$4))>1`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an A, Comment from [@Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478176/excel-condition-formatting-cells-flagged-as-false-duplicate-when-starting-with#comment66276073_39478176):

> The find duplicates {`Duplicate Values...`} must use something similar to COUNTIF().
>
> Use a formula instead:
>
> ```
>  =SUMPRODUCT(1*(B2=$B$2:$E$4))>1
> ```